# Encrypt password to connect Sybase from Perl script

Tags: perl, encryption, sybase, dbi, nagios

I'm using the "check_sybase" script from Nagios repository to monitorize a Sybase DB. 
The problem comes when that Sybase requires to encrypt the password on the network.
I'm using DBD::Sybase as driver to connect with DBI to Sybase. I've checked the documentation of this module and specifies that **"encryptPassword=1"** on the connection string would be enough. But it does not work. Here my connection string:

```
$dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Sybase:encryptPassword=1;server=$dbsvr;database=$dbname;".
               "charset=$charset;timeout=$timeout;".
           "loginTimeout=$timeout", $user, $pass)
    or &ncrit("Could not connect to '$dbname' on '$dbsvr'");
```

And the error message: **Adaptive Server requires encryption of the login password on the network.**

```
DBI connect('encryptPassword=1;server=XX;database=XX;charset=iso_1;timeout=15;loginTimeout=15','XX',...) failed: Server message number=1640 severity=16 state=2 line=0 server=XX text= **Adaptive Server requires encryption of the login password on the network.** Server message number=4002 severity=14 state=1 line=0 server=XX text=Login failed. OpenClient message: LAYER = (0) ORIGIN = (0) SEVERITY = (78) NUMBER = (34)Server XX, database Message String: Adaptive Server connection failed
```

No idea on how to solve this. 
Moreover, when I connect via isql with the command "-X" works fine.
Pd: I can only connect to those DB which don't require password encryption. I know that this attribute can be modified.